# Amazon MWS - Update inventory product quantity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I recently got into using the Amazon AWS but it looks quite weird to me. I thus far managed to get orders etc.

For a customer, he wants his private web store products to be synced with amazon. I'm aware that you can simply upload a .csv of the product inventory which we did.

Is there any way using the MWS (in php) to update the quantity? I'd preferably let a cron run every xxx hours to update the quantity at amazon as the stock may decrease if someone purchases anything outside amazon.

Couldn't really find anything relevant thus far, nor in the amazon nws scratchpad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this basically by uploading a stripped down CSV file that only contains the SKU and the new quantity (among with two or three other fields that are required).

You need to submit a feed to Amazon of type `_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_`.

Comment: Thank you, that brought me a step further. Unfortunately I can barely find anything related to PHP. I found how the xml file should be structured, but how would I go on transfering an XML file over a post request to them!? Do you happen to have any barebone of how you do it?

Comment: Actually we're doing it in C# through web service calls (Amazon provides DLLs with Stub-Classes for their WSDL files). So I can't really help you with the PHP details...

Comment: Thanks again! Got me further. Do you happen to know the correct format on how to update multiple SKU's at once? I have to regularly update the quantity of over 50000 products.. http://pastebin.com/12QPYmY5

Comment: We're using flat files. You can just download the product templates from your Amazon Seller Central page (Excel files) and then create a respective tab-delimited file that contains the required fields. It's important that the file includes the template header. All this is explained within the Excel files, too.